# I want 1 Spinner dependent on another spinner item

Tags: android, android-spinner

See I want when I choose China as a country in 1st spinner, So I want that 2nd spinner have to show all states of China it is done by my this coding.. BUT...!
My query is this when I choose state from second spinner it automatically set it as 1st value of second spinner
like if i have 3 values in second spinner
-"Shanghai"
-"Beijing"
-"Nanjing"
when I chooses Beijing it automatically return as Shanghai..!!
Help me out..!! :)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener
{

    String[] country = { "India", "Pakistan", "China"};
    String[] states_india = { "Delhi", "UP", "Bihar"};
    String[] states_china = { "Shanghai", "Beijing", "Nanjing"};
    String[] states_pak = { "Lahor", "Islamabaad", "Punjab"};
    int fee,tot=0,atot=0;
    Spinner spin0,spin1;
    private RadioGroup radioSexGroup;
    RadioButton r1,button1,button2;
    private EditText edittext1,edittext2;
    String Name;
    private TextView calc,detail;
    private Button clean;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spin0 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spin0.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        ArrayAdapter <String> c = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
        c.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin0.setAdapter(c);

        spin1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spin1.setOnItemSelectedListener((OnItemSelectedListener) this);
        spin1.setEnabled(false);

    //<!-- © 2013 Parth Shrarma -->
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        radioSexGroup = (RadioGroup)  findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
        button1 = (RadioButton)  findViewById(R.id.radioButton1);
        button2 = (RadioButton)  findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        edittext1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        edittext2=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        detail=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        calc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView6);



        calc.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                StringBuilder result=new StringBuilder();


                if(!edittext1.getText().equals("") && edittext1.getText().length() > 0 )
                {
                    Name = edittext1.getText().toString();

                }
                fee = Integer.parseInt(edittext2.getText().toString());

                int selectedId = radioSexGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                r1 = (RadioButton)  findViewById(selectedId);

                result.append("Details : \nName"+ Name);    


            }});

        clean=(Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        clean.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edittext1.setText("");
                detail.setText("Total : ");

            }
            //<!-- © 2013 Parth Shrarma -->
        });

    }

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

            spin1.setEnabled(true);
                        if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("India"))
                        {
                            ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_india);
                            s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spin1.setAdapter(s1);
                        }
                        else  if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan"))
                        {
                            ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_pak);
                            s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spin1.setAdapter(s2);
                        }
                        else  if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("China"))
                        {
                            ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_china);
                            s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                            spin1.setAdapter(s3);
                        }

        }    
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {                

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem may be with your *ItemSelectedListener*. As you set same listener for both spinners, must check which spinner is selected. You can check it with `AdapterView<?> arg0` parameter.
Here, you are calling `setAdapter()` repeatedly.

So, your code will change like,

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {

if(arg0.equals(spin0)){

        spin1.setEnabled(true);
                    if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("India"))
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter <String> s1 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_india);
                        s1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spin1.setAdapter(s1);
                    }
                    else  if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("Pakistan"))
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter <String> s2 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_pak);
                        s2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spin1.setAdapter(s2);
                    }
                    else  if(spin0.getSelectedItem().equals("China"))
                    {
                        ArrayAdapter <String> s3 = new ArrayAdapter <String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,states_china);
                        s3.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spin1.setAdapter(s3);
                    }
}
    }
```