# Undo spinner selection on some condition

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

Maybe a strange question. I have two `spinners`, both adapt values from the same `list`. Initially, I set them to different position. I need them always be different, i.e. user can never select in first `Spinner` the `String` that is already selected in second and vice versa. The simplest way I can think of is:

```
 spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                                        int position, long id) {
                if (position == spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                     //UNDO OR CANCEL THE SELECTION SOMEHOW
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
```

The question is how can I undo the selection of the spinner to previous one? Is it possible **without keeping global variable**? Thank you

Comment: see here for some hint http://stackoverflow.com/a/13750310/5202007 Or here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17808620/i-want-1-spinner-dependent-on-another-spinner-item

Comment: thanks, but the question is about "undo" possibility. I can resolve it via global variables with several conditions, but it is very interesting if we can achieve "undo" functionality via android sdk, anyway thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Stack for this:

```
Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
boolean programaticalyChange = false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Here initialize all you need
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (programaticalyChange) {
                programaticalyChange = false;
            } else {
                stack.push(position);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}
    });
//I use button to pop stack back, but you can use any callback from second spinner
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            programaticalyChange = true;
            if (queue.isEmpty()) {
                //no backstack available
                sp.setSelection(0);
            } else {
                if (queue.peek() == sp.getSelectedItemPosition()) queue.pop();
                sp.setSelection(queue.pop());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: there is misunderstanding. I need to set back the position of spinner, if the second already set to that position. Thus, I need to store position on Spinner click, but before onItemSelected triggered, because in this function position already changed. Stack in this scope nothing more but global value, anyway thanks! I start think that this is impossible.

Comment: I show you how to implement full backstack for spinner. There is no callback before position change, but you can extend a Spinner and add this functionality. For Example override method performClick

Answer (score 0):

Before your if condition get the previously selected item in some variable and if your condition gets true undo your selection using this variable.

Comment: " get the previously selected item" that is the question, how can I get it without pre-storing it in global variable ?

Comment: You can do it using getter and setters.

Comment: that is called seting global variable. I was asking of it is possible to do without